# How to create a line to a circle in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, lighting-effects

I am trying to make circular lighting effect as shown in this pics

[image]

I was thinking of using a gradient tool to make a straight line with dark blue and light blue colors. Then I was thinking of converting that line into a circle. That's where I am stuck at. I cannot make a line into a circle. I have googled it and polar coordinates filter just doesn't work. I am using adobe photoshop CSS

Does anyone know how they will approach this problem?

Comment: draw a path section the stroke it with simulate pressure

Comment: Please elaborate more. Step by step instruction would be great

Comment: Did you try googling [the key words](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=simulate+pressure)? Anyway there was a reason why I commented and did not answer. Anyway you ca also use a radial gradient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create circular shape with ellipse tool and set no fill on inside; apply gradient to stroke, set it to be angle-based, and set the angle to your liking. Hope it helps!

[image: Photoshop solution]

Comment: @SamB Glad I helped :)